# Frama-c : Trouble understanding WP memory models

Tags: frama-c

I'm looking for WP options/model that could allow me to prove basic C memory manipulations like :

- **memcpy** : I've tried to prove this simple code :

  ```c
  struct header_src{
    char t1;
    char t2;
    char t3;
    char t4;
  };

  struct header_dest{
    short t1;
    short t2;
  };

  /*@ requires 0<=n<=UINT_MAX;
    @ requires \valid(dest);
    @ requires \valid_read(src);
    @ assigns (dest)[0..n-1] \from (src)[0..n-1];
    @ assigns \result \from dest; 
    @ ensures dest[0..n] == src[0..n];
    @ ensures \result == dest;
  */
  void* Frama_C_memcpy(char *dest, const char *src, uint32_t n);

  int main(void)
  {
    struct header_src p_header_src;
    struct header_dest p_header_dest;
    p_header_src.t1 = 'e';
    p_header_src.t2 = 'b';
    p_header_src.t3 = 'c';
    p_header_src.t4 = 'd';

    p_header_dest.t1 = 0x0000;
    p_header_dest.t2 = 0x0000;

    //@ assert \valid(&p_header_dest);

    Frama_C_memcpy((char*)&p_header_dest, (char*)&p_header_src, sizeof(struct header_src));
    //@ assert p_header_dest.t1 == 0x6265;
    //@ assert p_header_dest.t2 == 0x6463;
  }
  ```

  but the two last assert weren't verified by WP (with default prover Alt-Ergo). It can be proved thanks to Value analysis, but I mostly want to be able to prove the code not using abstract interpretation.
- **Cast pointer to int** : Since I'm programming embedded code, I want to be able to specify something like:

  ```c
  #define MEMORY_ADDR 0x08000000
  #define SOME_SIZE 10
  struct some_struct {
      uint8_t field1[SOME_SIZE];
      uint32_t field2[SOME_SIZE];
  }
  // [...]
  // some function body {
      struct some_struct *p = (some_struct*)MEMORY_ADDR;
      if(p == NULL) {
          // Handle error
      } else {
          // Do something
      }
  // } body end
  ```

I've looked a little bit at WP's documentation and it seems that the version of frama-c that I use (Magnesium-20151002) has several memory model (Hoare, Typed , +cast, +ref, ...) but none of the given example were proved with any of the model above. It is explicitly said in the documentation that Typed model does not handle pointer-to-int casts. I've a lot of trouble to understand what's really going on under the hood with each wp-model. It would really help me if I was able to verify at least post-conditions of the memcpy function. 
 
Plus, I have seen [this](https://bts.frama-c.com/view.php?id=2078) issue about void pointer that apparently are not very well handled by WP at least in the Magnesium version. I didn't tried another version of frama-c yet, but I think that newer version handle void pointer in a better way.

Thank you very much in advance for your suggestions !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **memcpy**

  Reasoning about the result of `memcpy` (or `Frama_C_memcpy`) is out of range of the current WP plugin. The only memory model that would work in your case is `Bytes` (page 13 of the manual for Chlorine), but it is not implemented.

  Independently, please note that your postcondition from `Frama_C_memcpy` is *not* what you want here. You are asserting the equality of the sets `dest[0..n]` and `src[0..n]`. First, you should stop at `n-1`. Second, and more importantly, this is far too weak, and is in fact not sufficient to prove the two assertions in the caller. What you want is a quantification on all bytes. See e.g. the predicate `memcmp` in Frama-C's stdlib, or the variant `\forall int i; 0 <= i < n -> dest[i] == src[i];`

  By the way, this postcondition holds only if `dest` and `src` are properly separated, which your function does not require. Otherwise, you should write `dest[i] == \at (src[i], Pre)`. And your `requires` are also too weak for another reason, as you only require the first character to be valid, not the `n` first ones.
- **Cast pointer to int**

  Basically, all current models implemented in WP are unable to reason on codes in which the memory is accessed with multiple incompatible types (through the use of unions or pointer casts). In some cases, such as `Typed`, the cast is detected syntactically, and a warning is issued to warn that the code cannot be analyzed. The `Typed+Cast` model is a variant of `Typed` in which *some* casts are accepted. The analysis is correct **only** if the pointer is re-cast into its original type before being used. The idea is to allow using some libc functions that require a cast to `void*`, but not much more.

  Your example is again a bit different, because it is likely that `MEMORY_ADDR` is always addressed with type `some_stuct`. Would it be acceptable to change the code slightly, and change your function as taking a pointer to this type? This way, you would "hide" the cast to `MEMORY_ADDR` inside a function that would remain unproven.

Comment: Hi byako ! Indeed taking a (some_stuct*) parameter is a good solution. I isolated the cast to MEMORY_ADDR inside another function that also calls the function that was supposed to compute the cast originaly. I could even prove the cast thanks to Value plugin and then use WP to verify the whole contract. I also corrected the annotations for the memcpy functions, but still I was limited by WP memory models. To make things easier I wrote a custom memcpy that takes directly a pointer to the struct I want to copy. Thank you for your suggestions, that was very helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this example in the latest version of Frama-C (of course the format is modified a little bit).

### for the `memcpy` case

Assertion 2 fails but assertion 3 is successfully proved (basically because the failure of assertion 2 leads to a False assumption, which proves everything).

So in fact both assertion cannot be proved, same as your problem.

This conclusion is sound because the memory models used in the `wp` plugin (as far as I know) has no assumption on the relation between fields in a struct, i.e. in `header_src` the first two fields are 8 bit chars, but they may not be nestedly organized in the physical memory like `char[2]`. Instead, there may be paddings between them (refer to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) for detailed description). So when you try to copy bits in such a struct to another struct, Frama-C becomes completely confused and has no idea what you are doing.

As far as I am concerned, Frama-C does not support any approach to precisely control the memory layout, e.g. gcc's PACKED which forces the compiler to remove paddings.

I am facing the same problem, and the (not elegant at all) solution is, use arrays instead. Arrays are always nested, so if you try to copy a `char[4]` to a `short[2]`, I think the assertion can be proved.

### for the `Cast pointer to int` case

With memory model `Typed+cast`, the current version I am using (`Chlorine-20180501`) supports casting between pointers and `uint64_t`. You may want to try this version.

Moreover, it is strongly suggested to call Z3 and CVC4 through why3, whose performance is certainly better than Alt-Ergo.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect regarding the memory layout. Frama-C actually has a very precise view of the memory layout of aggregates. This includes padding, bitfields, etc. Furthermore, alignment directives such as `packed` for GCC or `aligned` for ICC are understood. In fact, Frama-C/Eva uses this information for this analysis. Here, the  problem is entirely due to the restrictions imposed by the existing WP memory models.

Comment: Hi Yi Li, Thank you for your suggestions. Since I didn't want to use arrays instead of structs, I just wrote custom memcpy that takes a pointer to the struct I want to copy, which is quite easier. As byako suggested, only byte memory model could work but it's not implemented yet. (btw I would be very interested to know if frama-c's team announced the release date of this feature). I also tried gcc's packed attribute with EVA and it works quite well.