# Satisfying Proof Obligations for memcpy? [Frama-C]

Tags: frama-c

We've been using Frama-C for 'experimental' static analysis on a commercial project (integrated into our CI, with a *few* selective blocking checks, on a small section of the overall codebase).

One of the snags that comes up relates to satisfying the proof obligations that the `wp` plugin generates anytime it encounters a `memcpy` call. Specifically, the three obligations below:
[image: memcpy_proof_obligations]

From the 'goal' notes, it looks like Frama-C is trying to prove that the destination and source memory are valid, .

I've tried adding `requires \valid()` preconditions, but that doesn't seem to help. In these instances, the `memcpy` call within the function under test is copying data from an input parameter to the function, and placing that data into a local variable (scoped within the function).

To further complicate matters, the local variable where the data is being copied is an attribute within a packed struct.

Concretely, I'm hoping that someone out there is able to share some real examples of `memcpy` uses where the goals introduced by `wp` can be satisfied (e.g. what preconditions must I add to make it provable?)

If it matters, I'm running Frama-C Magnesium-20151002 (according to apt-get on Ubuntu 16, this is 'up to date'), and invoking with the following parameters:

`frama-c -wp -wp-split -wp-dynamic -lib-entry -wp-proof alt-ergo -wp-report`

Also related, but missing a clear working example: [Frama-c : Trouble understanding WP memory models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51024378/frama-c-trouble-understanding-wp-memory-models)

Comment: Adding `-wp-model "Typed+Cast"` was enough to allow these proofs to be satisfied. Would definitely accept an answer that gives examples and further explanation of *why* this is the case, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you mentioned in you comment, the proper solution is to use `-wp-model "Typed+Cast"` in order to let WP accept casts to/from `void*` (more precisely, it will consider that `p` and `(void*)p` are the same thing for any pointer, which will be sufficient for proving the `requires` of `memcpy`). Now, as mentioned in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51071143/1633665) to the question you linked to, the main issue of this memory model (and the reason why it is not the default) is that it is **inherently unsafe**: it relies on hypotheses that by definition cannot be assessed by WP itself. Here is a small example that highlights this issue:

```c
int x;
char* c;

/*@ assigns c;
    ensures c == ((char *)&x);
*/
void g(void) {
  c = &x;
}

/*@ assigns \nothing;
    ensures \separated(&x,c);
*/
void f() {
}

void main () {
g();
f();
//@ assert \false;
}
```

Basically, the default `Typed` memory model ensures the separation between the location pointed to by `c` and `x` (i.e. the post-condition of `f`), because `int` and `char` are different, and you neither can prove the post-condition of `g` or use it as an hypothesis to derive `\false` in `main`, because the equality can't be expressed in the model at all.

Now, if you use `Typed+Cast`, the post-condition of `g` is now properly understood, and completely trivial to prove. WP won't let you prove at the same time that `&x` and `c` are separated, because they are involved together in an assignment. However, in `f` no such assignment exists, and the post-condition is also easily proved, leading to proving `\false` in `main` since we have two contradictory statements about `&x` and `c`. More generally, WP relies on a local alias analysis to track potential aliases between pointers of different types (a global analysis would defeat the purpose of having a modular analyzer). Passing option `-wp-model +Cast` can thus be seen as way to tell WP "Trust me, the program won't create miss-typed aliases". It is however possible to pass alias information by hand (or with the help of e.g. a yet-to-be-written global alias detection plug-in). For instance, with option `-wp-alias-vars x,c` the post-condition of `f` becomes `Unknown` (i.e. the separation between `&x` and `c` is not an assumption anymore, even for `f`).

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you! Some summary points I took away (restating to check if I've got the right idea):

1) If at any point a cast to/from a `(void*)` are performed, `Typed` memory model cannot analyze that pointer . 2) Using `-wp-model=Typed+Cast` lets the wp analyzer assume (unsafely!) that `p` and `(void*)p` are the same, regardless of the type of `p` (as long as `p` is a valid pointer). 

I'm not familiar with  the `/@assert \false` annotation and had some trouble following that part (naively, it seems like that statement should always fail?). How does that work?

Comment: @jjmilburn that's a good summary indeed. `/*@ assert \false; */` can basically mean two things (feel free to open a new question for more details, since "comments are not meant for extended discussion" ): either you have introduced a contradiction somewhere (this is the case here: `Typed+Cast` makes assumptions that are violated by the code), or you are on a dead statement (as `/*@ assert p; */` can be understood roughly as "for any execution _that reaches this point_ `p` holds").